# End program from a separate thread in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

I have a separate thread running a function. The function will check if it can do something, and if not possible I want the program to inform the user and end.

I know about `exit (0)`. I wasn't sure if it works on all threads or only in main.

**Is there a way I can end the program from a separate thread if a condition is not met?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the singleton for NSThread

```
[[NSThread mainThread] exit]
```

Otherwise if you're using Grand Central Dispatch you can access the main queue and fire it.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    exit(0);
});
```

Comment: Is there a way I can exit with a specific number? (I am talking about method 1).

Comment: Not with the NSThread exit method. You would have to use GCD or the older exit ways